# VS Code C extension doesn't support GCC nested functions

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gcc, nested-function

I edit my C code with VS Code (1.17.0) with C/C++ Extension (1.12.0) that provides error checking. I compile my code with GCC compiler that supports nested functions. So if I write this

```
int foo(int x)
{
    int bar(int x)
    {
        return x * 2;
    }
    return bar(x) + 1;
}
```

and compile it with gcc it works fine. However, the extension doesn't think so and red-squiggles the second curly brace with a "semicolon expected" error. The extension allows you to choose IntelliSense mode which I set to "windows-gcc-x64", however it doesn't seem to work. This issue exists since 2017. Is there a fix or a workaround?

Comment: *Is there a fix or a workaround?* Yes - don't use crazy extensions to the Standard C language.

Comment: The name "C/C++ Extensions" of VSC does not mean that it supports extensions to the C standard, as GCC has them. It is an extension of VSC. -- And yes, avoid language standard extensions at all cost.

Comment: @thebusybee Why don't you like extensions so much?.. Also, since the extension has a configurable IntelliSense mode that allows "windows-gcc-x64" parameter, I thought that it supports gcc geatures.

Comment: @Sun of A beach Do you create difficulties for yourself in order to successfully overcome them later?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I just don't understand what is that crazy about nested functions. A pretty common thing these days...

Comment: This is not the place to discuss language design reasons. As C is a language developed since decades, I am sure that their designers have good reasons to _not_ include nested functions to the standard. I have no problems with such a feature, I simply don't want to lock me and my successors into a certain compiler. Done that, had been bitten. If I need nested functions, I'd choose a language that supports it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C/C++ extension for VSCode does not support nested functions yet.

There is an issue open in their repo already, which you can track [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/1035).

*... it's been there since 2017 though*